# Oracle - Count with letters instead of numbers

Tags: oracle

I want to convert count to Letter in Oracle.Currently I am using below query.

```
SELECT DECODE ((SELECT COUNT(*)FROM MyTable), 0, 'A',
                                                      1, 'B',
                                                      2, 'C',
                                                      3, 'D',
                                                      4, 'E',
                                                      5, 'F',
                                                      6, 'G',
                                                      7, 'H') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Is there any particular oracle function which converts digit to letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My syntax may be wrong, but the [CHR function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions019.htm) is what you're after...

```
SELECT CHR(65 + COUNT(*)) FROM MyTable
```

...assuming you are using a character set in which "A" has a code of 65 and the letters are sequential after that.

Comment: +1 nice solution; OP could also limit the `count` with `least`, e.g. `SELECT CHR(LEAST (COUNT(*), <max value>)) FROM <table>;`

Answer (score 1):

You may use CHR(48+d), where d is the digit 0, 1, 2 etc